# software RAID alternative with file-level striping (not block striping)

Tags: file-merging

Is there a software RAID alternative with file-level striping?

I'd like the the total capacity of the disks in the set to sum up like in RAID-0, but i also want the individual disks to be still mountable individually.

*I know on Linux unionfs/aufs can combine multiple roots into one virtual directory, but it does not provide file-level striping.*

Besides, i also want to keep the disks formatted with a Windows-compatible filesystem like FAT32 or NTFS, so [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) in not an option.

[Linux LVM does not seem an option as well because it does not support file-level striping](https://serverfault.com/questions/614476/multi-volume-data-storage-without-striping).

Comment: No; you can not stripe files and still be able to mount only half of the stripe.

Comment: What OS(s?) will you want to run? I suppose more importantly, what's the main OS, since there's nothing I can think of that will be universal.

Comment: The main OS is Linux. Maybe the term "RAID" is not completely appropriate here, but i think it still describes the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the latest `aufs` [supports branch-balancing](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1611586), and there are also some fuse-based alternatives: [mergefs](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs) and [mhddfs](https://romanrm.net/mhddfs).

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking does not seem very logical or safe.  I've put these concerns aside for my answer -

You can't do this with block level tools, so looking for "RAID" solutions is not going to work.  Also, for this reason you will not find a solution which runs FAT32 or NTFS.  (RAID works at the block level, which sits below the filesystem)

You might want to look at abusing something like Gluster - I believe you could so this by setting up multiple bricks on different drives in the same system, which will, I believe, provide file level striping.   You would need to run the [Gluster](http://www.gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/GlusterFS_General_FAQ) server on a Linux type OS and then export it over NFS or CIFS or what have you.

Comment: I think it is safer than a RAID-0 setup where if a disk fails you possibly get all the files damaged. Obviously it is not as safe as RAID-1, but still looks good compromise IMO for storing small files.